# Issue with designing function for data scraping using BS4

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

Data which I require is present under 2 different combination of `tag + class`. I want my function to search under both combinations and present the data under both together. Both combinations are mutually exclusive. if 1 combination is present then other is absent.

Code which I am using is:

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
import csv
import urllib2
import sys
import urllib
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from itertools import islice

def match_both2(arg1,arg2):
    if arg1 == 'div' and arg2 == 'DetailInternetFirstContent empty openPostIt':
        return True
    if arg1 == 'p' and arg2 == 'connection':
        return True
    return False


page = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.sfr.fr/mobile/offres/toutes-les-offres-sfr?vue=000029#sfrintid=V_nav_mob_offre-abo&sfrclicid=V_nav_mob_offre-abo').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

datas = soup.findAll(match_both2(0),{'class':match_both2(1)})
print datas
```

Right Now, I am trying to use `match_both2` function to accomplish this, but it is giving me `TypeError` as I am passing only 1 argument to it and it requires 2. I don't know in this case how to pass 2 arguments to it, normally I would have called function something like this `match_both2(example1,example2)`. But here, I am not able to think of a method which can solve my problem.

Please help me in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a function to filter for matching elements, you pass in a reference to just the function, not it's result. In other words, you are *not* supposed to call it before passing it to `.findAll()`.

The function is called with only *one* argument, the element itself. Moreover, the `class` attribute has been split into a list. So to match your specific elements, you need to difen your match function as:

```
def match_either(tag):
    if tag.name == 'div':
        # at *least* these three classes must be present
        return {'DetailInternetFirstContent', 'empty', 'openPostIt'}.issubset(tag.get('class', []))
    if tag.name == 'p':
        # at *least* this one class must be present
        return 'connection' in tag.get('class', [])
```

This function returns `True` for a `p` tag with the `connection` class, or a `div` tag with all three classes present.

Pass this to `findAll()` *without calling it*:

```
datas = soup.findAll(match_either)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You have been a great help for a novice-learner like me.